# How to calculate the total value of each section separately: Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, input

I have more than 10 section that included three inputs in each section as follows:

```
<div class="product_quantity">
    <div class="color-quantity">
        <input onkeydown="return myFunction(event);" name="custom_small" class="custom_small" type="text">
        <input onkeydown="return myFunction(event);" name="custom_medium" class="custom_medium" type="text">
        <input onkeydown="return myFunction(event);" name="custom_large" class="custom_large" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="color-quantity">
        <input onkeydown="return myFunction(event);" name="white_small" class="custom_small" type="text">
        <input onkeydown="return myFunction(event);" name="white_medium" class="custom_medium" type="text">
        <input onkeydown="return myFunction(event);" name="white_large" class="custom_large" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

I am calculating the product quantity from each section but its giving me the whole amount of products on the basis of amount entered in every input. but i want the amount of products in section separately

I am using jQuery to do so please check the code and recommend the changes as required:

```
jQuery(".color-quantity input").each(function () {
    if (this.value) {
        quantity += (this.value) * 1;
        classname = jQuery(this).attr('class');
        arr.push(classname);
    }

    if (quantity == '') {
        quantity = 0;

    }
});
```

Comment: You can use `eq()` like `jQuery(".color-quantity:eq(0) input")`

Comment: can you please tell me how it will be work?

Comment: `.color-quantity:eq(0)` means 1st `.color-quantity`, `.color-quantity:eq(1)` means 2nd `.color-quantity` and so on...

Comment: But the reason is this i have more than 1000 products i cant do this manually by getting each input separately.

Comment: and in some products there are less option and some have more: please check this link:  http://quickpro.nextmp.net/index.php/bracelets/debossed-bracelet.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get total off each section as an array like following.

```js
var arr = $('.color-quantity').map(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $('input', this).each(function () {
        total += this.value * 1;
    });

    //do some stuff 
    if (total < 50) {
        $('.btn-cart').removeAttr("onclick");
    }

    return total;
}).get();

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color-quantity">
    <input type="text" value="1">
    <input type="text" value="2">
    <input type="text" value="3">
</div>

<div class="color-quantity">
    <input type="text" value="4">
    <input type="text" value="5">
    <input type="text" value="6">
</div>
```

Comment: your code works perfectly thanks for that its solve my first half: now i want to make a condition on each section separately if their calculated quantity is less than some number show an error: as follows: @Azim

 if(quantity < '50'){
            
            jQuery('.btn-cart').removeAttr("onclick");
}

Comment: you are the savior Bro: everything worked perfectly but the condition is running in wrong way :( @Azim

Comment: can i restrict the maping only for those sections that are selected only and remaining will not be included. right now it checking each 1000 section and user have to fill in each section 50 other wise he/she not able to do anything

Comment: I mean only those sections will be included that are being inputted and the condition will only applies for those that are selected

Comment: Use a class for selected section. Then use this class to map. @Xabby

Answer (score 0):

You might try a nested loop. first loop through the color-quantity divs, then through the inputs. like this:

```
jQuery(".color-quantity").each(function () {
    var quantity = 0;
    $(this).find('input').each(function() {
        if (this.value) {
            quantity += (this.value) * 1;
            classname = jQuery(this).attr('class');
            arr.push(classname);
        }

        if (quantity == '') {
            quantity = 0;
        }

    });
    // here is where you can get the total value for each div
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain little more how i will be able to calculate the amount where you mentioned:  @David784